# Using varchar parameter in exec()

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

I am trying to execute my whole stored procedure as a string since I have to make the condition dynamic.
Here is my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP1
  (@VoucherType varchar(10),
  @ProductID bigint,
  @BrandID bigint)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Condition as varchar(300)
SET @Condition=' WHERE VoucherType=@VoucherType '
IF (@ProductID<>-1)
  BEGIN
  SET @Condition=@Condition+' AND ProductID='+cast(@ProductID as varchar)
  END
IF (BrandID<>-1)
  BEGIN
  SET @Condition=@Condition+' AND BrandID='+cast(@BrandID as varchar)
  END
EXEC('SELECT * FROM Products '+@Condition)

END
```

Filtering by `ProductID` and `BrandID` are optional (if their values are not -1 then those conditions are added to where clause). And filtering by VoucherType is compulsory. The problem is that I can't get the value of the parameter `@VoucherType` in line:

```
SET @Condition=' WHERE VoucherType=@VoucherType '
```

The error says there is no column Named SI (Which was my input for `@VoucherType`).
How can I get the value of that parameter.

Comment: This could be done without dynamic sql, with `or` or `case` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it without a dynamic SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE VoucherType=@VoucherType AND 
  (@ProductID=-1 OR  ProductID=@ProductID)
  AND 
  (@BrandID=-1 OR  BrandID=@BrandID)
```

Comment: It select when `@ProductID` =-1, doesn't it? I trying to filter the results by `@ProductID` unless its value is -1. In fact, there is not Product record whose `ProductID` is -1.

Comment: @user2983160 `@ProductId` is not a field from your table is a parameter of the stored procedure. The idea here is when you call SP with @ProductId=-1 (means NO FILTER applied) then this condition selects ALL records but when you call SP with `@ProductId=<Id you need>` then the second condition of `OR` works `ProductID=@ProductID` and you get only rows with `ProductID` you need.

Answer (score 1):

If the logic is as you describe, you can do this without dynamic SQL - just using the parameters directly in the where clause by using a comparison with your default values for each parameter (essentially making that part of the where clause a no-op if the values are at the value you use to signal for "don't filter").

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sp1
(
  @VoucherType VARCHAR(10),
  @ProductID   BIGINT,
  @BrandID     BIGINT
)
AS
  BEGIN
      SELECT *
      FROM   Products
      WHERE  (@VoucherType IS NULL OR VoucherType = @VoucherType)
             AND (@ProductID = -1 OR ProductID = @ProductID)
             AND (@BrandID = -1 OR BrandID = @BrandID)
  END
```

Note you should probably only select the columns you need rather than `*` though.

(If you don't want VoucherType to be optional as I've made it here, just remove the NULL comparison)

Comment: There is no default value for `@ProductID` and `@BrandID`. It just describes, whether I want to filter with them or not. Filtering by `@ProductID` is added to the where clause unless its value is -1.

Comment: @user2983160 Thanks for the feedback - I've edited to try and phrase my description better - the logic is the same though :)

Answer (score 1):

Why isn't it working? Because you're trying to use the parameter. You'd need to change this:

```
SET @Condition=' WHERE VoucherType=@VoucherType '
```

to this:

```
SET @Condition=' WHERE VoucherType='' ' + @VoucherType + ''''
```

**NOTE:** You could actually do this without dynamic SQL. Consider the following statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Products
WHERE (VoucherType = @VoucherType) AND
    (@ProductID = -1 OR ProductID = @ProductID) AND
    (@BrandID = -1 OR BrandID = @BrandID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sp_executesql which receives 3 parameters: the query, parameter types and the parameter values:

Short example only for @VoucherType parameter:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM Products WHERE VoucherType = @VoucherType',
N'@VoucherType VARCHAR(10)',
@VoucherType = @VoucherType
```

Then you should do the same trick for ProductID and BrandID.

Other suggestions:

1/ Use NULL instead of -1 and check against NULL:

```
IF BrandID IS NOT NULL
```

2/ Depending on your physical design you can rewrite your statement without sp_executesql

```
SELECT * FROM Products
WHERE VoucherType=@VoucherType
AND @ProductID IS NULL OR ProductID = @ProductID
AND @BrandID IS NULL OR BrandID = @BrandID
```